# Update teamcity pipeline in a branch

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-2019

I have an existing teamcity pipeline which is running fine.
We use teamcity dsl to define the same.
I want to replace this with a new pipeline. I am experimenting with this pipeline in my own branch. When I try and push my change, I see this error

> [Retrieve settings, revision: f16566918ecccbe079d02bd3c3689575408a0957] Read build settings from revision f16566918ecccbe079d02bd3c3689575408a0957
>   [10:01:05]  [Read build settings from revision f16566918ecccbe079d02bd3c3689575408a0957] Failed to load build configuration settings from VCS: build configuration config is not found, use current settings from TeamCity server

Internal teamcity experts are asking me to do my development on a test teamcity environment we have.

Is this the only option?
Is there a way I can force teamcity to pick a new dsl based pipeline defined in a branch?

Comment: It isn't possible now. A server tries to apply settings from a branch, but there is a limited set of the applicable changes (check here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/storing-project-settings-in-version-control.html#StoringProjectSettingsinVersionControl-DefiningSettingstoApplytoBuilds).
Also, here is the related feature in development, that should solve the problem https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-42533. You can vote it and describe you case.